# Salt-minion tries to connect old salt-master instead of new salt-master

Tags: salt-stack

I had connected the salt master (10.1.x.x) to salt minion (10.2.x.x). Now I have changed the salt master(131.x.x.x) for existing salt minion and also I have changed the public key of new salt master in place /etc/salt/pki/minion. But the salt master still tring to connect old master . I checked in minion configuration file , no ip was configured for saltmaster. Can anyone tell me how did the salt-minion picks salt-master ip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salt minions will by default try to connect to a hostname called `salt`. If no IP is specified, and if minion is able to resolve `salt`, it will attempt to join that master.

It's possible that the hostname `salt` is pointing to old master's IP address. Something simple like `ping salt` from minion should be able to reveal some clues.

If it is indeed pointing to 10.1.x.x, then you have to change the DNS entry or `etc/hosts` entry to point to the new IP 131.x.x.x.